# Match URLs containing a specific word

Tags: regex, xml

I am trying to extract URLs from a XML document that are found within a `url` element attribute and contain the string `"s144"`.

I am trying to do this in NoteTab Light and have tried to figure out how to write regular expressions but just can't seem to wrap my head around it. I am not a programmer: so you can imagine I am lost.

The XML file is a Google Picasaweb album RSS feed:
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/100688803282112893010/albumid/6140734189321131313?alt=rss&kind=photo&hl=en_US

Here is what I have:

```
(?s)url\s*?=\s*?'(.*?)'
```

It matches URLs in a `url` attribute, but I need to narrow it down to ones containing `"s144"`.

Ultimately I am trying to take a list of the URLs and rewrite them into image thumbnails linked to the full image.

```
<a href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-5veHcnzHMRE/VTmFk66WJoI/AAAAAAAAIBs/kCUSSxylUAo/s1920-Ic42/35%252520Docked%252520with%252520210BR.jpg">
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-5veHcnzHMRE/VTmFk66WJoI/AAAAAAAAIBs/kCUSSxylUAo/s144-Ic42/35%252520Docked%252520with%252520210BR.jpg" />
</a>
```

How can I narrow down matches to just URLs that contain `"s144"`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074740/how-to-extract-urls-from-a-xml-file

Comment: Note that [NoteTab Light reportedly uses Perl-compatible regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoteTab#NoteTab_regular_expressions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work well against [the XML file you provided](https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/100688803282112893010/albumid/6140734189321131313?alt=rss&kind=photo&hl=en_US):

```
url\s*=\s*'(\S*?s144\S*?)'
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/cyuR5HgXYN_kvlec)

Comment: The Debuggex demo worked well against the entire XML file the OP provided, but I could not save it with the entire XML file: so I saved it with about half the XML file's `item` elements, which still clearly demonstrates the regex's behavior.  To run the demo against the entire XML file, just paste its contents into the appropriate text area on the demo's page.

Comment: Thanks J0e, that makes a lot of sense. I tried to figure this out for about 3 hours on my own and got nowhere. I appreciate you taking the time to answer this for me.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
(?s)url\s*?=\s*?'([^']*?s144[^']*?)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?s)url\s*?=\s*?'(.*?/(s\d+-).*?)'
```

Explanation for `.*?/(s\d+-).*?` part:

- `.*?` - looks like you already know what is this.
- `/(`  `)` - some portion of url, that starts with backslash
- `s` - ... followed by `s` symbol (means `size`, I guess...)
- `\d+` - followed by at least one digit
- `-` - followed by `minus` character

Comment: Thanks. It seems to match too much but your explanation is certainly helpful.